# Subtracting percentage from itself when it's over 100%

Tags: ms-access, percentage

I have spent over 5 hours searching the web.

I am calculating an average finish time from a race based on a target

e.g.   Swim Time   0:23:06

Target    0:18:00

Percentage    128.33%

What I am looking to achieve is..

When the percentage equals >100% to then subtract the amount over from 100%

In the above example the amount I would expect to be displayed would be:-

(100% - 28.33%)  = 71.67%

Comment: You can use iif() function

Comment: So entries with swim time 0:19:00 and 0:17:00 will both have a percentage of ca. 95%? That makes not much sense.

Comment: Makes perfect sense Andre. I someone has not finished at the target time they have gone past being 100% so goes back down the scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
100 - ((Abs(Target - SwimTime)/Target)*100)
```